# how to get the multiple mode in an array?

Tags: java, android, math

Hi i'm am making a program that computes the mean, median and mode... The computation of mean and median is already done but I have a  problem in computation of mode. The program only displays the lowest mode. What if there are multiple mode?Please help me. Thank you:)

```
    final AutoCompleteTextView inputValues = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_input);

    final TextView txtTotalNum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_totalNumber);
    final TextView txtMean = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_mean);
    final TextView txtMedian = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_median);
    final TextView txtMode = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_mode);

    Button btnCalculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncalculate);
    btnCalculate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View arg0){


            //get the total number of values entered
            String []values = ( inputValues.getText().toString().split(","));
            int[] sortedValues = new int[values.length];
            txtTotalNum.setText(Integer.toString(values.length));

            //compute for the mean
            double meanResult=0;
            double totalValues=0;
            int e=0;
            for(e=0;e<values.length;e++){
                totalValues += Double.parseDouble(values[e]);
                sortedValues[e]= Integer.parseInt(values[e]);
            }
            meanResult= totalValues/values.length;
            txtMean.setText(Double.toString(meanResult));

            //compute for the median
            Arrays.sort(sortedValues);

            int elementNumber=0;            
            if (sortedValues.length %2==0)
            {
                elementNumber= sortedValues.length/2;
                txtMedian.setText(Double.toString((sortedValues[elementNumber-1] +sortedValues[elementNumber] )/2 ));
            }
            else
            {
                elementNumber= (sortedValues.length + 1)/2;
                txtMedian.setText(Integer.toString(sortedValues[elementNumber-1]));
            }

            //compute for the mode

            int maxValue = 0;
            int maxCount=0;

            for (int i = 0; i < sortedValues.length; ++i) {
              int count = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < sortedValues.length; ++j) {
                  if (sortedValues[j] == sortedValues[i]) ++count;
                   }
            if (count > maxCount) {
            maxCount = count;
            maxValue = sortedValues[i];
            }

            txtMode.setText(Integer.toString(maxValue));


        }

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an ArrayList instead of an array so that you can save bimodal values too.. hope it helps

```
ArrayList<Integer> maxValues = null;
int maxCount=0;

for (int i = 0; i < sortedValues.length; ++i) {

  int count = 0;
  for (int j = 0; j < sortedValues.length; ++j) {

    if (sortedValues[j] == sortedValues[i]) {
      ++count;
    }
  }

  if (count == maxCount) {
    maxValues.add(sortedValues[i]);
  }

  if (count > maxCount) {
    maxCount = count;
    maxValues.clear();
    maxValues.add(sortedValues[i]);
  }
}
```